# Strange while line appear in the html

Tags: html, css

[image]

Can't get rid of this line anyway , here's the domain , please switch to browser mobile mode to open it  .   http://www.pocketsaver.co/index.php?route=mobile/home

Comment: Can you post your HTML and CSS as a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: I can't see this error at all - how exactly are you seeing it (which page, what search... etc?) It does not show up on my screen.

Comment: I've updated the url , press F12 if your using chrome to enter mobile vision mode .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a rogue h4 element floating over the top of your content.

```
.hotlists h4:before {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #ffffff 16%, #ababab 53%, #ffffff 83%);
    content: "";
    height: 1px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

I'm not sure the result you were expecting but if you remove position, right and top it will sort itself into the DOM with everything else and stop floating over your content.